# convert collection to array by type

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I tested this code:

```
Collection l = new ArrayList<Object>();

l.add(5);
l.add("test");
l.add(6);

Integer[] arr= l.toArray(new Integer[2]);
```

I tried to get only Integers from this collection and got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2248)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:389)
    at c.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

May be there is an other way to filter but I need to understand the `toArray(Object[] a)` method. Why can't I filter by telling type and size of the array?

Comment: `toArray` is _not_ intended to filter the collection; passing an array of a specific type to `toArray` is an instruction to copy the _whole_ collection to that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the java doc of the method. Each method works as per the contract it declares to the outside world (as per the signature or java doc).

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a); Clearly says in its java doc the below statement.
```

> Throws:ArrayStoreException - if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this collection.

In your case type of each of your element is not `Integer`.

Answer (score 4):

> Why i can't filter by telling type and size of the array?

Because that's not what `toArray()` does, and nowhere does it say it can be used as a filter.

Functions & API's have definitions for what they do (and sometimes *how* they do that). You can't expect a function to do what you want it to do if it's not designed to do that.

Answer (score 4):

`toArray` attempts to store the **entire** collection in the given array. If you want to filter it, you'll have to do so yourself. E.g.:

```
Integer[] arr = 
    l.stream().filter(x -> x instanceof Integer).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj The edit does not improve the readability of the code

Comment: It does improve it a lot.